# Accessing SearchDescriptor properties for testing

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nunit, nest

I am separating my query building and query execution, so I have a QueryBuilder which returns a `SearchDescriptor<Video>`

So to put it into context in my Web Api Controller:

```
SearchDescriptor<ElasticVideo> documentQuery = _queryBuilder.BuildDocumentQuery(elasticSearchParameters);
ISearchResponse<ElasticVideo> documentResults = _videoRepository.Search(documentQuery);
```

But when it comes to testing the QueryBuilder I can't access any of the properties on the SearchDescriptor returned in order to validate my test, for example:

```
        [Test]
        public void BuildDocumentQuery_WithEmptyPhrase_ReturnsProperlyFormedQueryDescriptor()
        {
            var elasticSearchVideoQueryBuilder = new ElasticSearchVideoQueryBuilder();
            var descriptor = elasticSearchVideoQueryBuilder.BuildDocumentQuery(new ElasticSearchVideoParameters());
            descriptor.// How can I get the raw query?
        }
```

I can see in the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Nest/DSL/SearchDescriptor.cs) that there doesn't appear to be anything to expose this? Does anyone else have a similar problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly how do you build your query, but you can cast `SearchDescriptor` to `ISearchRequest` to get more details.

```
var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticsearchProject>()
    .From(0)
    .Size(20)
    .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.OnField(f => f.Country).Query("Country")));

var query = ((ISearchRequest) searchDescriptor).Query.Match.Query;

Assert.AreEqual("Country", query);
```

Comment: Accepted.  That's much more elegant.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `searchDescriptor as ISearchRequest`.

Comment: I cannot make this work. the `.Match` part is always `null`.

Comment: @beruic What version of NEST do you use?

Comment: Well, I just realized that this is 1.8.0, so that's probably the issue. I'm having a hard time upgrading because someone made some strange use of attributes in our models.

Comment: @beruic that still should work for 1.8.0. May you create other question and add details about your query?

Comment: Not sure about that, but I got what I wanted by using the serializer as described in the other answer.

Comment: Just upgraded to 2.3 and now it definitely does not work. `.Match` is no longer available.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1994#issuecomment-208681266) answer from Russ helpful?

Comment: Sorry for the long answering time. Using `client.Serializer.SerializeToString()` is actually what I have ended up using. It would however be nice if I could get the query without having to ask the client.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a way around this, but it means I will have to parse the JSON string back into an object

```
        var elasticSearchVideoQueryBuilder = new ElasticSearchVideoQueryBuilder();
        var descriptor = elasticSearchVideoQueryBuilder.BuildDocumentQuery(new ElasticSearchVideoParameters());

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:123"));
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.Serializer.Serialize(descriptor));
```

Comment: In Nest 2.3.1 you can simply do `string jsonString = this._client.Serializer.SerializeToString(descriptor);`

Comment: Why will you have to parse the JSON string back into an object? You still have the `descriptor`, which is reusable.